# SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation does not exist error during migration at deployment to heroku

Tags: mysql, postgresql, laravel-5, heroku

I am working on a laravel 5.8 project. The app works well with mysql database on localhost.
While deploying to heroku, i provisioned and set up heroku postgresql database. However, during migration to heroku, i keep getting this error message:

```
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "locations" does not e
  xist (SQL: alter table "users" add constraint "users_location_id_foreign" f
  oreign key ("location_id") references "locations" ("id"))


In Connection.php line 458:

  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "locations" does not e
  xist
```

My users table comes before my locations table. users table has a foreign key column (location_id) related to locations table. My users migration file:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('location_id')->references('id')->on('locations');
    });
```

and my locations migration file:

```
Schema::create('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

My guess is that its reporting the error because locations "does not exist" at the point of running the users migration (which comes before locations).
So how do i fix this?